# mysql on dreamhost via mac terminal

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, dreamhost

I am trying to access mysql on dreamhost via a mac terminal.  From the terminal I can do: 
[ssh -l username domain] to successfully log in to my dreamhost account.  Then when I enter [mysql -u username -p password -h hostname database], I get a list of help information about mysql (version 14.14).

However, the prompt doesn't turn into mysql> or anything, just the normal dreamhost prompt.  When I try to enter mysql commands such as [show tables;], I get the error message [-bash: show: command not found].  If I try to type in [mysql>show tables;] I get the message "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket..."

Do you know how I can set the prompt to mysql> or do whatever it takes to get the mac terminal to recognize the mysql commands when I am connected to my dreamhost account and the remote mysql serve?  Thanks!

More details: I can successfully manipulate my databases on dreamhost using PHPMyAdmin, but am having trouble accessing them via the mac terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a list of help informations, you probably entered something wrong with regards to the params. I think the problem is your "database" part at the end. Just use mysql -u username -p password -h hostname and when you are in, then type use database.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  Weird, what I had to do was enter [mysql -h hostname -u username -p].  Then it prompts me for my password, and I finally get the mysql prompt.  Any other combination gave me an error!